# save() prohibited [...] due to unsaved related object, but related object already saved

Tags: django, django-database

I'm working with Django 4.0.1.

I'm having having **"save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'page'"** even if the 'page' object is saved one line before.

Here is the code:

```
# Upload entity data
u = Upload(
    message=request.POST["upload_msg"]
)
# saving u here to be able to use u.datetime later
u.save()
# new page for the upload entity
page = Page(
    title="notes for Upload " + str(u.datetime),
    content="This page is empty..."
)
page.save()
u.page = page
u.save()
```

The last line (u.save()) is the one causing the error.
**Am I having some kind of race condition here? Isn't it assured that the previous db operations are complete before trying to run the next?**
Any other ideas?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I can see from the admin panel that the Upload and Page instance are both created correctly but the Upload instance does not have a Page id set.
Unless I'm misunderstanding the error message the Page instance does not result saved (or updated inside the python 'page' variable) when the last u.save() call is invoked. Any way to solve this?

**UPDATE 2**
Looks like this problem arises only if I explicitly define the primary key as follows:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
```

Shouldn't this automatically create the entities' ids on .save()?

Comment: Use a `models.AutoField` instead of a `models.IntegerField` for your primary key, an `AutoField` will generate and assign a new value on creation. Better yet, delete your custom field completely and let Django auto-generate an `id` field for you

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a solution. Is there some docs somewhere that explain why explicitly defining that id field is not equivalent? My understanding was that a field defined as in update2 should have auto increment by default...

Comment: The docs for the field describe its auto-increment behaviour https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key. It's not the case that any IntegerField will also auto increment if a primary key, that's the explicit purpose of the AutoField.

Comment: Thank you. If you want to recap this in an answer I can mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `save()` but not storing instance of it in `u` and use `commit=False` this will not hit database it will store instance in memory after your proccess is finished you can save it. check more info about [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method.

```
# Upload entity data
u = Upload(
    message=request.POST["upload_msg"]
)
# saving u here to be able to use u.datetime later
u = u.save(commit=False)
# new page for the upload entity
page = Page(
    title="notes for Upload " + str(u.datetime),
    content="This page is empty..."
)
page.save()
u.page = page
u.save()
```

Comment: Thank you. I thoight the save method changed the internal status of the instance in Place. The documentation coming out in vscode showed None as return value.

Comment: This did not solve my problem. The save method this comment is about is in the ModelForm class. The one I'm using is in the Model class.